# ModelForm's drop-down box for Foreign Key not in alphabetical order

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have created a foreign key field in the "ReviewComments" model and have included the command "order_with_respect_to". However, the drop-down box that appears in the webpage does not sort the service providers by alphabetical order. Is there something that the code is missing?

Models.py

```
class ServiceProvider(models.Model):
    identification_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, )
    license_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True, )
    individual_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, )
    corporate_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, )
    reg_address = models.CharField(max_length=180, )
    email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True, )
    land_line = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, )
    hand_phone_line = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, )
    service_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.individual_name, self.service_type)

class ReviewComments(models.Model):
    comment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    receipt_document = models.FileField(upload_to='receipt_document', default=None, )
    service_provider = models.ForeignKey(ServiceProvider, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True, )

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'service_provider'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + "\n" + self.comment
```

Forms.py

```
class ReviewForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ReviewComments
        fields = ['title', 'comment', 'service_provider', 'receipt_document', ]
        widgets = {
            'title': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 1}),
            'comment': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 10}),
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order_with_respect_to` is not what you are looking for. That will order your `ReviewComments` with respect to their corresponding `ServiceProvider` - it does not alter the order of the `ServiceProvider`.

If you want your service providers to be listed alphabetically then you need to set the default [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#ordering) on the the `ServiceProvider` model, specifying which field you want to order by:

```
class ServiceProvider(models.Model):

    # ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['individual_name']
```

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me crazy!